# Destructor issue

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Which is the difference between these two codes? Is there a memory leak in the first case?

no destructor defined

```
 class Library
{
private:
    Book books[50];
    int index;
public:
    Library()
    {

        index=0;
    }
};
```

or with destructor defined

```
class Library
{
private:
    Book *books;
    int index;
public:
    Library()
    {
        books=new Book[50];
        index=0;
    }
    ~Library()
    {
        delete books;
    }
};
```

Comment: The second has UB. The first has no memory leak. The second also brings in the rule of three/five.

Comment: i am a beginner with oop and i don't know what UB means or which is the rule three/five

Comment: "Rule of three C++" can be easily googled -- and UB means "Undefined behavior", ie your compiler could choose to blow up your house in response to what you are doing, and it would be standards-compliant.

Comment: [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), [Rule of Five](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11), [Rule of Zero](http://rmartinho.github.com/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html), [Different Kinds of Behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

Comment: Prefer using `std::vector<Book> books;`.

Comment: Also, prefer using member initializers in constructors instead of assignment. E.g., `Library() : index(0) {}` rather than `Library() { index = 0; }`.

Comment: Looks like you haven't read your C++ book all the way through yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
delete books;
```

should be

```
delete[] books;
```

In the second one: `books` is allocated as an array, so must be deleted as an array. The first version does not have a memory leak.

The difference is that in the first case the memory for `books` is is contained within the allocation for each instance of `Library`, wheras in the second case it is allocated separately, using the heap.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the second code should be

```
~Library() {
  delete[] books;
}
```

`new` must be matched with `delete`, `new[]` must be matched with `delete[]`.

In the first code, every instance of `Library` contains 50 instances of `Book`. Copying a `Library` will copy those 50 instances. There is no memory leak.

In the second code, an instance of `Library` contains just a pointer to the books. Copying the instance (without the default copy constructor) copies just the pointer - the original and copy will share the 50 books, and whoever is destroyed second will issue `delete` on already deleted memory, which is an error.

Answer (score 1):

```
~Library()
{
    delete[] books;
}
```

is a proper solution. There are free possible problems in your code, which you can consider:

1) use initialization list

in second case:

2) Do you really need to do pointer? isnt a local object enough?( i guess your books doesnt exceed stack size). Look at your code you are creating it at the beginning and delete at the end. Remember stack is faster and more safety.

Also be familiar with valgrind, its a really great tool. Check if cppcheck will help you. "sudo apt-get install cppcheck" in ubuntu.